# How to add input from a prompt to the local time using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

I'm a software engineering student in an Intro to JavaScript course and I'm stuck on an assignment. Here's the assignment,

in a file named alarmTime.html, use prompt() to find out how long the user wishes to nap. Then, write a statement to the document telling the user what time her/his alarm should go off. Be sure the times are local for the user.

I'm stuck on adding the input to the user's local time. I don't really know what I'm doing wrong and I'm having difficulty understanding what to do because all I'm getting is what seems to be random numbers. Please take a look at my code and point me in the right direction.

```
    var howLong = prompt("How long, in hours, do you want to nap for?", 1);
    var parsedInput = parseFloat(howLong);

    var today = new Date();
    var currentTime = today.toLocaleTimeString();
    var myHour = today.getHours(currentTime);

    var alarm = today.setHours(myHour + parsedInput); 


    document.write(alarm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because of this statement `document.write(alarm);`. `setHours` method in Date object updates the Date instance, and returns the Date in milliseconds. Therefore, you are printing the Date object as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970. To fix that, simply replace it with `document.write(today);`

Comment: Why is it that `var today = new Date();` outputs the correct information when I write it to the page and not the `alarm` variable.

Comment: Because the Date instance in `today` is updated with `today.setHours(myHour + parsedInput);` later on. Therefore, it contains the correct information and the correct instance (Date instance). Meanwhile, `alarm` variable contains int instead of Date instance because `setHours` returns the number of milliseconds of the updated Date instead of the Date instance.

In addition to that, it is not generally a good practice to assign the return value of any setter methods to a variable. In general, setter methods are not returning anything (return type `void`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is var alarm = today.**setHours**(myHour + parsedInput);

instead try to set the variable as

> var alarm = **today.getHours();**

or change document.write(alarm); to document.write(today);

Answer (score 0):

Date.now() will give you current time (users local time). Add time from prompt and your good:

```
let napTime = prompt('how many minutes do you want to nap?');
let alarmTime = new Date(Date.now()+napTime*60000);
//if you want to get HOURS instead of minutes
//let alarmTime = new Date(Date.now()+napTime*3600000);

//print it out. toLocale...() functions return local FORMAT of the datetime,
//they dont deal with timezones
document.write('set alarm to '+alarmTime.toLocaleTimeString('en-US'));
console.log(alarmTime);
```